# how to use the spinning.gif image on a web application

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a canvas html5 web app:-

I am trying to add the 'spinning.gif' image while the canvas is loaded via sql queries.

```
<div id="someHiddenDiv" style="display:none;"><img src="/../spinner.gif"/>... Please Wait, the Browser is Working ...</div>
```

So far, I have thought of this as my script to produce my idea.

However, this has a few problems.

**1) image is not totally visible, since the top part of my page is a panel (text box, buttons)
and the rest of it is a canvas 800 by 950 (which is also scrollable from side to side).
2) image is not centered.
3) the letters are not visible, because the the panel's height is short enough to show the first 4 circles of the spinning.gif image.**

what I would ideally like:-

panel-1 has a textbox. Once user inputs information in the textbox and presses submit button, The whole page should go to the background and the spinning.gif image should come to the foreground. Once query is complete(ajax) then canvas is painted, the spinning.gif image goes away and the page is intractable.

Here is the beginning of my page:-

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <span class="style1"><strong>&nbsp;<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="#999966"
        BorderStyle="Double" Height="129px" Style="margin-top: 0px" Width="913px">
        &nbsp; <span class="style2">&nbsp;Enter Member ID: </span>
        <br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" 
            BorderColor="Silver" Height="20px" Style="margin-left: 6px" Width="136px"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" Font-Bold="True" 
            Height="28px" OnClientClick="store_memID(); return false;" 
            Style="margin-left: 20px" Text="Submit" Width="78px" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" BackColor="#99FF99" 
            BorderColor="Gray" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="2px" 
            Font-Names="Arial Unicode MS" Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="Black" 
            Height="77px" OnTextChanged="TextBox4_TextChanged" ReadOnly="True" Rows="3" 
            Style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="193px"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" BorderStyle="Groove" Text="&lt;&lt;&lt; Past"
            Width="69px" Height="23px" style="margin-top: 0px" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" BorderStyle="Groove"
            Style="margin-left: 28px" Text="Future &gt;&gt;&gt;" Width="78px" 
            Height="23px" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" Text="Today" Width="63px"
            Font-Bold="True" Height="23px" onclick="Button9_Click" />



                 <%--       <asp:UpdateProgress ID="pnlWait" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="Panel1" runat="server">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                           <div style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                        <img src="/../spinner.gif" alt="Please wait..." style="padding: 0px;
                            margin: 0px" />
                        <span style="font-size: small; color: #8969A5;">Finding your search. Please
                            wait...</span>
                           </div></ProgressTemplate></asp:UpdateProgress>--%>
<%--
       <p align="center"><asp:Image ID="ImageStatus" ImageUrl="/../spinner.gif" runat="server" />
       <h1><asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text="Loading Please wait..."></asp:Label></h1></p>
        --%>

<div id="someHiddenDiv" style="display:none;"><img src="/../spinner.gif"/>... Please Wait, the Browser is Working ...</div>

    </asp:Panel>
        <br />
    </strong></span>





    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>





    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="915" height="850" style="border: 2px double #000000;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="balloon" width=105 height=105></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Please try to narrow down your problem. Saves time for those who like to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had great luck using spin.js for these kinds of spinners: http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/

It's a great library, uses CSS but falls back on older browsers.